# The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found - Blazor .Net 8.0 program.cs

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Why am I getting this warning?

Inside the program.cs code file of my Blazor web application (.net 8.0).
The web app runs fine, but I want to get rid of this warning:

"The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found..."
in the app.MapRazorComponents<**App**>() ... line

[image]

Comment: Try `dotnet clean` on solution or project level

Comment: Visual Studio bugs. Very common to get this issue, especially in larger projects, it happens A LOT. Sometimes I have to manually delete the bin and obj folders from projects and sometimes even the solution .vs folder. I have also seen this issue after a new dotnet version has been released if I have not updated dotnet and or Visual Studio. So check for updates also. Also try closing and reopening the tab (or all tabs.)